# How can I download all poll data from Facebook messages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-messenger

I've been running polls daily with a number of friends in a group chat. I would like to download these and run some data analysis over them to surprise my friends with at the end of this year.

Is there any way to download the messenger poll data into a clean format? I'm hoping to use pandas in python to manipulate and analyse the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download all your Facebook data, and then search for the polls in the downloaded conversations files.

### To download Facebook data, and find the conversation

1. [**Download your entire Facebook data.**](https://www.facebook.com/help/302796099745838)

> **To download a copy of your Facebook data:**
>
> 1. Click  at the top right of any Facebook page and select **Settings**.
> 2. Click **Download a copy of your Facebook data** below your General Account Settings.
> 3. Click **Start My Archive**.

```
You'll get an email when the archive is ready for download.
```

2. **Navigate to the desired conversation.**

   - Open the archive folder you downloaded.
   - Open `index.htm` and navigate to **Messages**
   - Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search your friend's (or group) name.
   - Open the conversation and search what you want (it's a single page, so everything is there!).

---

Maybe you'll have it for the next end of year!